# Color management via VNC?

Tags: macos, color

We want to share a Mojave Client via VNC to a Grahic Agency.
We ran about the question, how the color informations are transmitted. We normally do color management with a calibrated monitor locally.

I didn't find helpful information on how VCN transmits color information.

Can someone give me a hint on this?

Comment: By “do color management” how do you do that now?

Comment: Never tested VNC, but I have tested Apple RDC & MS RDC between calibrated displays on various machines in the building. It is good enough for evaluation purposes. I'd say "within one" on the Mac's colour meter & also as I can run between the Macs, it "looks about right" when you sneaker over to another machine. I'd assume you'd be working in sRGB for something like this anyway - not sure I'd trust P3. [I've looked at Windows over RDC, but never for anything important, so less sure about that].

Answer (score 2):

Use a known reference to calibrate your local and remote displays. No other approach will be able to provide a consistent or predictable result.

[VNC is a protocol](http://web.mit.edu/cdsdev/src/howitworks.html) and not an implementation. Both client and server implementations will make their own decisions about colour management.

Where available, ensure your VNC server and client are using their maximum quality settings available. This will help reduce visual differences introduced during video encoding and decoding.

## Colour Encoding

It is likely the VNC service will use macOS's [Quartz Display Services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/quartz_display_services) to access and then transcode the contents of the display.

[`CGDisplayStreamCreate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455170-cgdisplaystreamcreate) is the function used to gain access to the display and the call can request a specific pixel format. The colour space used is set as a property to this call, see [`kCGDisplayStreamColorSpace`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/kcgdisplaystreamcolorspace).

This means that the colour space and colour information will depend on the [VNC server](https://dssw.co.uk/reference/vnc/) used.

You may also find the VNC client alters the colour output.

Do not rely on VNC for faithful colour reproduction. Calibrate the output displays.